# Passive voice from Active voice

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

Over 2500 years ago,King Okkalapa decided and built
a shrine on Singuttara Hill.

1)A shrine was purposely built on Singuttara Hill by
King Okkalapa over 2500 years ago.

2) A shrine was built on Singuttara Hill over 2500 years
ago with the decision of King Okkalapa.

Which is correct? If not,let me know the correct answer(s).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We usually say "decide **to** do sth" rather than "decide **and** do sth." "decided" is then the main verb in your sentence. Also, I don't think the king built the shrine himself! At most, he had it built.

That said, we have at least two possible passive versions for your sentence:

3) Over 2500 years ago, (under the reign of King Okkalapa,) **the decision was made** (by King Okkalapa) to build a shrine on Singuttara Hill. (You have to choose just one of the phrases between parentheses -- only the second one indicates that it was the king who made the decision.)

4) Over 2500 years ago, (under the reign of King Okkalapa,) **it was decided** to build a shrine on Singuttara Hill.

To tell you the truth, I like (3) better than (4).

Comment: If you say *"the king decided to build"*, it doesn't imply that the king built it. I don't know if you meant that, but it certainly reads like you did.

Comment: I find "had it built" or "ordered the building/construction of" to be more accurate.